npm install fails for git dependency
Why am I getting the below error while doing npm install?
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects clone -b build ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<mygitrepo>.git C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneBveAZy --recurse-submodules --depth=1 --config core.longpaths=true
npm ERR! fatal: destination path 'C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneBveAZy' already exists and is not an empty directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

verbose error 
npm verb stack Error: An unknown git error occurred
npm verb stack     at makeError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\make-error.js:28:13)
npm verb stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\git\lib\spawn.js:37:26
npm verb stack     at async Object.withTempDir (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\fs\lib\with-temp-dir.js:23:14)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1108:19)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:976:11)npm verb stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:218:7) 
npm verb stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:153:5)
npm verb stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:156:5)
npm verb stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm verb node v16.16.0
npm verb npm  v8.11.0
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred

npm install should resolve my git dependency for a branch

You can try to clear the npm cache :
npm cache clean --force


tried. still issue exists
